# C++ GTK program won't start on Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17.3

Tags: c++, linux, gtk3, glade

I made a program written in C++, I used Glade to make the GUI. The program compile just fine and it works with no problems under Fedora 23.
Here's the problem: if i try to run this program on Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17.3 it just doesn't start. I launch the program with "./Name" (yes i have permission) but nothing seems to appears. I tried with the command top but i can't even see the name of my program. 
I tried with a simple program (open a windows that says Hello World) and it works, i can't understand why.
Note that i have installed all the dependencies and that the program compile with no error, of course.

PS: on Ubuntu 16.04 it works, this doesn't make any sense to me.

Here's the code https://github.com/MegamanBitch/psw-manager

Comment: Can you please post your code for reference.

Comment: Sure https://github.com/MegamanBitch/psw-manager

Comment: Did you recompile the program on those other distributions?  If not, are you sure they all have compatible versions of your runtime dependencies? Or did you bundle all your runtime dependencies with the application and ensure it would use your bundled versions (usually done by using the `-rpath` linker option with a relative path based on `$ORIGIN` pointing to the bundled libraries)?

Comment: Yes, i did make cleanAll and i recompiled with no problems. Here's the makefile https://github.com/MegamanBitch/psw-manager/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Older ubuntu use the nouveau video driver for Nvidia cards.  That driver does not support CUDA.

Comment: Always check for API calls returning error codes.  They will tell you why it is failing.

Comment: @brianbeuning it doesn't work also on the newest Mint. I don't get any error when i run the program.